# Trouble with freeing malloc'd 2d array in C

Tags: c, arrays, multidimensional-array, malloc

I have had trouble freeing my array. I have tried different methods, tried freeing by just one for loop, but I am honestly really stuck. Here is my code, any help is appreciated!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

int r,c,i,j, *array;
  int sum = 0;
  array = (int *)malloc(r*c*sizeof(int));

  printf("Enter the number of rows: ");
  scanf("%d", &r);
  printf("Enter the number of columns: ");
  scanf("%d", &c);

  for(i=0;i<r;i++){
    for(j=0;j<c;j++){
      array[i*c+j] =+ i+j;
      sum = sum + array[i*c+j];    
  }
  }
  printf("The sum of the array is: %d",sum);
  for(i=0;i<r;i++){
    for(j=0;j<c;j++){
      free(array[i*c+j])
}
  }
  free(array);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: What trouble? Does it crash? Does it have a leak? Does it not compile?...? Please be specific.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to include this, what is happening is that when I run this I am getting that "argument 1 of free makes point from integer without a cast" as well as "expected void * but argument of type int" now I have tried casting these and both and still have had no luck, maybe I incorrectly casted but Im not sure

Comment: Can you post the code with your 2D array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off, you're allocating the array before you even know what the dimensions are...this will lead to undefined behavior, as `r` and `c` have undefined values.

To fix it, move the `malloc` call after the two `scanf`s.

Second, you only call `malloc` once - thus, you only need to/should call `free` once. Get rid of the two `for` loops with the `free` in the middle.

Comment: thank you so much, I don't know why I could not have caught that I made the malloc statement before scanning. My instructor told me to free using a loop so I was just confused thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

[In call to `malloc()`, few variables e.g. `r`, `c` have undefined values. Place the call after they are initialized.]

`free()` is necessary only for what you `malloc()`. Since `array` is the only thing malloc-ed, so that is the only thing that need to be freed; the calls to `free()` in the loops are <s>unnecessary</s> incorrect.

Comment: Minor note: it's not that they're unnecessary, they're outright wrong.